# NPE while opening BIRT report file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, reporting-services, nullpointerexception, birt

Recently I created report in eclipse Kelper (4.3.2) with BIRT things installed.

In dynamic web project I created report for customer - privacy policy - can not attach it, but it is simple.

It has:

1 database connection

2 data sets

1 grid

2 tables

1 chart

and added some scripts to check if startDate and endDate is higher than 31 days or not - according this some of above parts will be visible or not.

Everything works fine when I design it. Even "View Report" shows results that makes me happy about completed work.

But when I shut down Eclipse, start it again and want to open report design then no design shows - only information about NullPointerException appears

[image]

I also paste log file content. (not all because of limit of characters in post)

```
    eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=pl_PL
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

This is a continuation of log file C:\birt workspace\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2014-09-26 13:25:52.432

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-26 13:25:52.433
!MESSAGE Could not create action delegate for id: org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.actions.PreviewToolbarMenu

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-26 13:25:52.435
!MESSAGE Internal plug-in action delegate error on creation.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.actions.PreviewToolbarMenuAction.isEnable(PreviewToolbarMenuAction.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.actions.PreviewToolbarMenuAction.selectionChanged(PreviewToolbarMenuAction.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.refreshEnablement(PluginAction.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.createDelegate(PluginAction.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.selectionChanged(PluginAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.refreshSelection(WWinPluginAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.<init>(WWinPluginAction.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginPulldown.<init>(WWinPluginPulldown.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionDescriptor.createAction(ActionDescriptor.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionDescriptor.<init>(ActionDescriptor.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginActionSetBuilder.createActionDescriptor(PluginActionSetBuilder.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginActionBuilder.readElement(PluginActionBuilder.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.RegistryReader.readElements(RegistryReader.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.RegistryReader.readElementChildren(RegistryReader.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginActionBuilder.readElement(PluginActionBuilder.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.RegistryReader.readElements(RegistryReader.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginActionSetBuilder.readActionExtensions(PluginActionSetBuilder.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginActionSetBuilder.processActionSets(PluginActionSetBuilder.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionPresentation.setActionSets(ActionPresentation.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.updateActionSets(WorkbenchWindow.java:2058)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$ActionSwitcher.updateActionSets(WorkbenchPage.java:793)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$ActionSwitcher.updateTopEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActiveEditorSources(WorkbenchPage.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateBroughtToTop(WorkbenchPage.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$17(WorkbenchPage.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partBroughtToTop(WorkbenchPage.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$6.run(PartServiceImpl.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartBroughtToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.access$4(PartServiceImpl.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4688)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$21(WorkbenchPage.java:3034)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3016)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3012)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2976)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2967)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.OpenAndExpand.run(OpenAndExpand.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$3.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-26 13:25:52.440
!MESSAGE Could not create action delegate for id: org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.actions.PreviewCascadingMenuGroup

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-26 13:25:52.442
!MESSAGE Internal plug-in action delegate error on creation.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.actions.PreviewCascadingMenuGroup.isEnable(PreviewCascadingMenuGroup.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.actions.PreviewCascadingMenuGroup.selectionChanged(PreviewCascadingMenuGroup.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.refreshEnablement(PluginAction.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.createDelegate(PluginAction.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.selectionChanged(PluginAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.refreshSelection(WWinPluginAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.<init>(WWinPluginAction.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginPulldown.<init>(WWinPluginPulldown.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionDescriptor.createAction(ActionDescriptor.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionDescriptor.<init>(ActionDescriptor.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginActionSetBuilder.createActionDescriptor(PluginActionSetBuilder.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginActionBuilder.readElement(PluginActionBuilder.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.RegistryReader.readElements(RegistryReader.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.RegistryReader.readElementChildren(RegistryReader.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginActionBuilder.readElement(PluginActionBuilder.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.RegistryReader.readElements(RegistryReader.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginActionSetBuilder.readActionExtensions(PluginActionSetBuilder.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginActionSetBuilder.processActionSets(PluginActionSetBuilder.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionPresentation.setActionSets(ActionPresentation.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.updateActionSets(WorkbenchWindow.java:2058)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$ActionSwitcher.updateActionSets(WorkbenchPage.java:793)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$ActionSwitcher.updateTopEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActiveEditorSources(WorkbenchPage.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateBroughtToTop(WorkbenchPage.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$17(WorkbenchPage.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partBroughtToTop(WorkbenchPage.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$6.run(PartServiceImpl.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartBroughtToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.access$4(PartServiceImpl.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4688)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$21(WorkbenchPage.java:3034)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3016)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3012)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2976)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2967)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.OpenAndExpand.run(OpenAndExpand.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$3.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

I tried run eclipse with -clean parameter or even make clean eclipse install (then create new report project and paste created report) but it does not help.

So it looks like problem is with report itself..

Could you please take a loot at logs?

Best regards,

bez

Answer (score 0):

When you reinstall BIRT, are you using the same workspace you were using before? If so, there might be a corruption there. If you are, try defining a new workspace or deleting your old workspace and start from scratch. Let me know.

If that's not it, could you email me a sample design that uses the Classic Models Inc Sample Database that shows this issue to mwilliams.actuate at gmail dot com? Thanks.